# type mismatch when running reduceLeft

Tags: scala

I have a `ConfigRule` trait which has `transform` method as

```
trait ConfigRule {
  final def transform(doc: Node): Node = { .....}
}
```

Then I have `ConfigTransformer` which looks like  has `transform` method as

```
trait ConfigTransformer {
    def transform(doc: Node, rules: Seq[ConfigRule]) = {
    rules.reduceLeft((x, y) => x.transform(doc).andThen(y.transform(_)))
  }
}
```

I try to run this as

```
object Runner extends App {
  override def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val n1 = NewNodeRule(<foo/>, <bar/>, Seq.empty, "adding bar under foo")
    val n2 = NewNodeRule(<garage/>, <car/>, Seq.empty, "adding car under garage")

    ConfigTransformer.transform(<Root/>, Seq(n1, n2))
  }
}
```

I get compilation error as

```
Error:(18, 56) type mismatch;
 found   : PartialFunction[Int,scala.xml.Node]
 required: solutions.xml.ConfigRule
    rules.reduceLeft((x, y) => x.transform(doc).andThen(y.transform(_)))
```

What is that I am doing wrong?

Comment: `transform()` returns a `Node`. What is the definition of `Node`? How/why is it supposed to have the `andThen()` method on it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not a Scala expert yet but the problem is that you don't return object of type `ConfigRule` in `reduceLeft` statement (it's a `Node` and that's why you get an error). What you are looking for is I guess `foldLeft`. Here's an example:

```
trait ConfigTransformer {
    def transform(doc: Node, rules: Seq[ConfigRule]) = {
        rules.foldLeft(doc)((d, x) => x.transform(d))
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for

Answer (score 3):

Well... the thing is that reduceLeft for a `Seq[A]` has following signature,

```
def reduceLeft[B >: A](op: (B, A) ⇒ B): B
```

Which means that your reduce function `op` should take an `accumulator: B` and `currentElem: A` and should return a `B` where `B` is some `super-class` of `A`.

One important thing to notice about `reduceLeft` is that the first reduction ie. the first calculation of the `accumulator` is done using the first and second elements of `Seq` as parameters.

In other words... only elements in the `Seq` participates in `reduceLeft`.

For the use-cases where you want to start with some other value as the initial accumulator you such as this, you should use `foldLeft`, which has the following signature,

```
def foldLeft[B](z: B)(op: (B, A) ⇒ B): B
```

Notice that it take an initial `accumulator: B` (`z` here) and a `fold` function as parameters. Also... `B` here can be any type that you want, without any relation to A. And this is exactly the case for you,

Now, if you wanted to do this with `foldLeft`,

```
trait ConfigTransformer {

  def transform(doc: Node, rules: Seq[ConfigRule]) =
    rules.foldLeft(doc)((acc, elem) => elem.transform(acc))

}
```